# I am using this package, namespace Volo.Abp.AuditLogging and it is generating dll files

Tags: audit-logging

I am using this package, namespace Volo.Abp.AuditLogging and it is generating dll files. I want to comment out the [DisableAuditing] attribute in the generated audit class file. I am using net6.0 and packages are

I don't want to use wrapper class but want to modify it and comment out [DisableAuditing] as I want to log in my sql tables.